# right and left arrow keys does not work for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, arrow-keys

Hy,

I want to add the ability for players to navigate between the four numbers in the photo using their arrow keys with cross-browser compatibility;

[image]

I write the code, but works only with up and down arrow keys, it seems not work with left and right arrow keys, I dont why; here my code

```
<template name="range">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
<div class="valueSliders">

<!-- Verticle Number Selector -->
<div class="verticleNumberSelect">
  <span class="firstNumber">
    <span class="up"> </span>
    <span class="numberValue" tabindex="1">0</span>
    <span class="down"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="secondNumber">
    <span class="up"></span>
    <span class="numberValue" tabindex="1">0</span>
    <span class="down"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="thirdNumber">
    <span class="up"></span>
    <span class="numberValue" tabindex="1">0</span>
    <span class="down"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="fourthNumber">
    <span class="up"></span>
    <span class="numberValue" tabindex="1">0</span>
    <span class="down"></span>
  </span>
  <input type="hidden" id="verticleNumber" />

</div>
</div>
</div>


</div>
</template>
```

and my js is

```
Template.range.events({

     'keydown .numberValue':function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == '38') {
      counter = $(e.target).text();
    if (counter < 9){
      counter++;
    numberValue = $(e.target).text(counter);
    totalNumber(); 
  }
  } else if (e.keyCode == '40') {

     counter = $(e.target).text();
    if (counter > 0){
      counter--;
    numberValue = $(e.target).text(counter);
    totalNumber(); 
  }
} else if(e.keyCode == 39){
  var li = $('.numberValue');
  var liSelected; 
        if(liSelected){
            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
            next = liSelected.next();
            if(next.length > 0){
                liSelected = next.addClass('selected');

            }else{
                liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
            }
        }else{
            liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');

        }
    }else if(e.keyCode == 37){
      var li = $('.numberValue');
      var liSelected;
        if(liSelected){
            liSelected.removeClass('selected');

            next = liSelected.prev();
            next.focus();
            if(next.length > 0){
                liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
            }else{
                liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
            }
        }else{
            liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
        }
    }
  }

  });
```

Am I doing something wrong above ??

knowing that it's a Meteorjs application

Thank's for help

Comment: Just curious, why do you put the keyCode in quotes in some places and not in others?  It shouldn't affect anything, but you should be consistent.  2) do you have an online example?  The community will be more likely to help something they can see; it's faster to debug something that you can interact with, then read through code.

Comment: Thank's for your note about quotes, I ll fix it;  for the example ,please  check this link [link](http://koud.meteor.com/game) . thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that `var liSelected;` should look like `var liSelected = li.filter('.selected');` because otherwise it will never get initialized.

Also `liSelected.prev()` and `liSelected.next()` will not work because this will search for the `liSelected`'s previous or next sibling in the DOM while your '.numberValue' items are within separate containers.

The working version would look like below. Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/beb0ajco/):

```
    } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        // right        
        var li = $('.numberValue');
        var liSelected = li.filter('.selected');          
        if (liSelected.length>0) {
            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
            var posSelected = li.index( liSelected );
            next = posSelected+1;
            if (next < li.length) {
                liSelected = li.eq(next).addClass('selected');
            } else {
                liSelected =li.first().addClass('selected');
            }
        } else {
            liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
        }
    } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        // left
        var li = $('.numberValue');
        var liSelected = li.filter('.selected');          
        if (liSelected.length>0) {
            liSelected.removeClass('selected');
            var posSelected = li.index( liSelected );
            next = posSelected-1;
            if (next > -1) {
                liSelected = li.eq(next).addClass('selected');
            } else {
                liSelected =li.last().addClass('selected');
            }
        } else {
            liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank's man for help; I change my code and let you know about the result :). I appreciate your help